# Resources for learning Zürich German

Tags: resource-request, german

I have recently become interested in learning the German language as spoken in Zürich. As far as I am aware, there are genuine differences in how the cases are used, the standard word order, etc. between Zürich German and the standard German. One issue is that apparently nobody writes in Zürich German (except possibly on Facebook).

Are there any books or online resources that can help me to learn Zürich German?

Answer (score 1):

German Wikipedia has a section with links, the three middle ones of which work at the moment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%BCrichdeutsch#Weblinks

- http://www.schweizer-deutsch.ch/
- http://www.spraach.ch/index.php?id=17
- [http://www.züritütsch.ch/](http://www.z%C3%BCrit%C3%BCtsch.ch/)

The same page also has a section for "Lehrmittel", https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%BCrichdeutsch#Lehrmittel, which I assume to mean resources for learning the dialect. It lists

- Arthur Baur: Schwyzertüütsch. «Grüezi mitenand.» Praktische Sprachlehre des Schweizerdeutschen. (faktisch: Zürichdeutschen). Winterthur 1969. (seither zahlreiche Neuauflagen bis heute, ISBN 978-3-85701-002-6.)
- Ann Beilstein: Lehrmittel Züritüütsch / Schweizerdeutsch. ISBN 3-033-00413-X (siehe auch www.schweizer-deutsch.ch).
- Renate Egli-Wildi: [Züritüütsch verstaa, Züritüütsch rede](https://web.archive.org/web/20100218113935/http://www.spraach.ch:80/zuerich/mitglieder/renate-egli/Verstaa-Rede.php). (Memento vom 18. Februar 2010 im Internet Archive) Mundartlehrgang des Vereins Schweizerdeutsch, Gruppe Zürich. Küsnacht 2007, ISBN 978-3-033-01382-7.

Presumably the entire Wikipedia page and the other written resources listed there are also useful.